# How exactly does the JavaScript expression [1 [{}]] parse?

Tags: javascript, parsing, literals

Can you explain how the JavaScript expression:

```
[1 [{}]]
```

parses/evaluates?  In Firefox, Chrome, Konqueror, and rhino, it seems to create an array with a single element, `undefined`.  However, I don't understand why.

In Firefox:

```
[1 [{}]].toSource()
```

produces

```
[(void 0)]
```

Replacing 1 with other JavaScript values seems to yield the same result.

Update: I think I understand now. codeka, Adrian, and CMS clarified things.  As far as the standard, I tried to walk through ECMAScript 5.

1. `1 [{}]` is a Property Accessor, so it's covered in §11.2.1.
2. `baseReference` is the result of evaluating `1`, so still `1`.
3. `baseValue = GetValue(baseReference) == 1`.
4. At `GetValue` (§8.7.1), `Type(1)` is not `Reference` (a resolved name binding), so return 1.
5. `propertyNameReference` is result of evaluating `{}`, so an empty object.
6. `propertyNameValue = GetValue(propertyNameReference) == {}`
7. At `CheckObjectCoercible(baseValue)` (§9.10), we return (Number is object-coercible).
8. `propertyNameString = ToString(propertyNameValue)`
9. At `ToString` (§9.8), return `ToString(ToPrimitive({}, hint String))`
10. At `ToPrimitive` (§9.1), return result of object's `[[DefaultValue]]`, passing `PreferredType` (string).
11. At `[[DefaultValue]]` (§8.12.8), let toString be result of `[[Get]]` with argument `toString`.
12. This is defined at §15.2.4.2 to return `"[object " + [[Class]] + "]"`, where `[[Class]]` is "Object" for the default object prototype.
13. Since there is a callable `toString`, we call it with argument `this` being  `{}`.
14. Return a value of type `Reference`, whose base value is `BaseValue` (1) and whose referenced name is `propertyNameString` (`"[object Object]"`).

We then go to Array initializer (§11.1.4), and construct a single element array with the result.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be valid JavaScript...so you get unpredictable results of the engine *trying* to handle it...seems status normal to me.

Comment: @Nick, I'm also skeptical that it's valid JS, and I'm willing to accept the possibility it's simply undefined behavior.  However, the fact that all 4 engines (which have separate implementations) parse it the same way is at least interesting.

Comment: @Matthew - Adrian's answer is a pretty good explanation of the behavior in those 4 browsers, I still don't think `[object]` is a valid accessor though...so it would still be up to each engine on how it would handle this case.  This is an edge case though, and I can't find anything in the 3.1 spec that says how it should be handled exactly.

Comment: @Nick, it seems to be valid for ECMAScript 5 at least.  I tried to walk through it above.

Comment: @Nick: `[object]` is valid, but `object` will be converted to a string.

Comment: @Matthew - I agree that's happening, I'm wondering what string that is though, can't tell since the `GetValue()` implementation isn't exposed, I'm *guessing* it's "undefined", but that's the part of ECMA 3.1/5 I can't find.

Comment: @Nick, it's `"[object Object]"`.  This is defined at ECMA 5 §15.2.4, and CMS gives a simple way to test it.

Comment: @Matthew - Ah gotcha...I feel like an idiot...didn't refresh this page until just a moment ago, good trace through it, +1 and you and CMS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we break it up a bit, you'll see:

```
var foo = 1;
var bar = {};
var baz = foo[bar];

[baz];
```

I believe it's valid JavaScript, but I'm not an expert...

Comment: I think you have it.  I probably didn't see this because it's unusual to use a number as a JavaScript object, and the empty object is an unusual key.  Do you have any thoughts on the `[(void 0)]` part?

Comment: @Matthew: My guess is that since `1[{}]` is undefined, `(void 0)` is simply the interpreter's "canonical" form for representing "undefined".

Answer (score 15):

Reading the [OP and Nick comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081479#comment-3158104), I think I can expand a little bit more the [Adrian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081479/how-exactly-does-the-javsascript-expression-1-parse/3081542#3081542) to make it clearer.

It's perfectly valid JavaScript.

JavaScript handles object property names as strings, objects cannot contain other types or other objects as *keys*, they are just strings.

The bracket notation [property accessor](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.1) (`MemberExpression [ Expression ]`) implicitly converts the expression between brackets into a string, so:

```
var obj = {};
obj[{}] = "foo";
alert(obj["[object Object]"]); // foo
```

In the above example you can see that I assign a value to the `{}` property, and `{}.toString()` (or `{}+''`) produces the string `"[object Object]` (via [`Object.prototype.toString`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.2.4.2)).

The expression `1 [{}]` implicitly converts the 1 `Number` primitive to an object (this is made by the property accessor) and it lookups a property named `"[object Object]"` the property lookup is made on the `Number.prototype` and the `Object.prototype` objects, for example:

```
1['toString'] === Number.prototype.toString; // true
```

Finally, the `1 [{}]` expression is itself enclosed in brackets (`[1 [{}]]`), this is actually an Array literal.

In conclusion here is how the parser evaluates the expression:

```
 [1 [{}]];
 //   ^ The accessor expression is evaluated and converted to string

 [1 ["[object Object]"]];
 // ^ A property lookup is made on an Number object 
 //   trying to access a property named "[object Object]"

 [undefined];
 //   ^ the property is obviously not found

   [undefined];
 //^         ^
 // An array literal is created with an element `0` which its value is `undefined`
```

Answer (score 8):

It is because you are trying to get the property `{}` of the object `1` and then place it in an array. `1` doesn't have the property `{}`, so `1[{}]` is `undefined`.

If you replace the `1` with an array, you will see how it is working. With `1` as `[5]` and `{}` as `0`, it is `[[5][0]]`.

Also, keep in mind that `obj['property']` is the same as `obj.property`.