# playing with javascript objects and functions, discovered this (probably common)

Tags: javascript

ok, I was experimenting (getting straight in my head) all this object oriented like stuff javascript can do, and Im simulating inheritance with functions, adding functions to functions (too cool!) and I had a AHA! moment.

```
var myArray = [function(){console.log("im in an array!");}, 2, "fly feet!"];
myArray[0]();
```

Of course, now that Ive done it, Ill find its a common thing and useful for somesuch thing... BUT I DISCOVERED IT!!!

Anyone care to share their AHA! moments?

Comment: Good job, now make this a Community Wiki :)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hidden Features of JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript)

Comment: Not a javascript guy, but I am an OO developer. Had to punch this into an HTML file and test it. Nothing! What was I supposed to notice?

Comment: console.log is a firebug object / function, so if youre not using firefox with that addon, I believe it wont work. In that case, the fix would be replace console.log(...) with document.write(...) or just alert(...). The thing it does thats cool is stuffing a function into an array, and then calling it with array notation. For me, its starting to blur the line between functions, arrays, and other objects.

Comment: Ok, I got alert to work. So, basically, the array values 2 and "fly feet" do nothing - as I suspected, but I wasn't certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I understood the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081479/how-exactly-does-the-javascript-expression-1-parse):

> How exactly does the JavaScript expression `[1 [{}]]` parse?

Your AHA moment is an example of [first-class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_functions).

Comment: I realized thats what it was, that was the specific thing I was (have been) studying. I'd never seen it done in an array, had to try it, was all happy it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I had an AHA moment. After learning that <del>*everything*</del> most things in JavaScript are objects, I realized that something like this is possible:

```
console.log("I'm not wearing pants".replace('not ', ''))
// Produces: "I'm wearing pants"
```

As is this:

```
foo = function(operation) {
  operation();
}

pants = function() {
  console.log("I'm not wearing pants!!");
}

foo(pants); // Produces console output of "I'm not wearing pants!!"
```

Comment: Not *everything* in JavaScript is an object, there are *primitive values* such string, number, boolean, undefined, and null *values*. There are also primitive value wrapper objects, for string, number and boolean values, e.g.: `typeof "" == "string"; // primitive` vs `typeof new String("") == "object"; // primitive wrapper`

Comment: whoa... very cool. That seems very close to how eval works.

Answer (score 1):

Since functions are first-class objects in JavaScript, you can use them anywhere you would use an object, that includes storing them in an array or even doing things like returning a function from another function.

```
function one() {
    alert("one");
    function two() {
        alert("two");
    }
    return two;
}

one()();
```

Comment: Whats happening with the ()(); ? 

edit NM I figured it out. One() evaluates to two, which gets the other () slapped on it. Badass.